# What type of field do I have to use in order to associate related parent object in serializer

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have two models with one to many relation. I will use the default example.

```
class Album(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    album_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Track(models.Model):
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, related_name='tracks', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    order = models.IntegerField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    duration = models.IntegerField()
```

The question I have is how do I implement serializer in order to associate a track with an album by providing only Album 'id' key.
What I want is to know which type of serializers.Field do I have to declare is the serializer.

Here is an example

```
class TrackSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
     album = serializers.MagiclyRelatedFieldByUUID() # <---- ???
     title = serializers.CharField()
     order = serializers.IntegerField()
     duration = serializers.IntegerField()

     class Meta:
         model = models.Track
```

Request looks like this:

```
{
  'album': '137b5a6c-dd76-11e6-bf26-cec0c932ce01',
  'title': 'my new track',
  'duration': 10
  'order': 31
}
```

**Updated**

I managed to solve it with a HyperlinkedRelatedField by specifying view_name='album-detail', queryset=models.Album.objects.all() and lookup_field='uuid', but in this case I have to send a valid url to the album. Is it the only way to get instance of related model in serializer?

So far it my solution is following:

```
class TrackSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
     album = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(view_name='album-detail', queryset=models.Album.objects.all(), lookup_field='uuid')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the album to be

```
album = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=models.Album.objects.all())
```

then you can create a basic create method to the serializer as

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    return models.Track(**validated_data)
```

Assuming you are not doing anything special then that should work. I have verified that posting

```
{
    "album": "ed79716c-ba5d-4d3f-bb96-2685b38139e5",
    "title": "Eleanor Rigby",
    "order": 2,
    "duration": 206
}
```

to a viewset configured to use that serializer will create a Track linked to the correct Album

Comment: ehmm.. that's not how it works. If I specify it as a CharField what I get would be a string u'137b5a6c-dd76-11e6-bf26-cec0c932ce01' and I need an instance of Album model.

Comment: Yeah, what I had was wrong, have updated it with tested code. But you shouldn't have to worry about conversion between the ID and the Object provided it has been declared as a Related Field

Comment: Thank you, James!

Do you mean that I can assign uuid to the appropriate property and it will just work if the field was declared as Related Field in the model?

Comment: Yes, it should do so

Answer (score 1):

You can even try this

```
album = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        queryset=models.Album.objects.all(),
        slug_field='uuid'
    )
```

It will accept you model uid to get the object.

```
{
    "album": "ed79716c-ba5d-4d3f-bb96-2685b38139e5",
    "title": "Eleanor Rigby",
    "order": 2,
    "duration": 206
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Ashish. I think in case of OneToMany it is more appropriate, right?

Comment: No, It will work for foreign key also. I have tried on ForeignKey field just like your model.

Comment: Sorry, let me rephrase it, Would you use SlugRelatedField over PrimaryKeyRelatedField in my example?